# sorting a table for latex output with xtable

Tags: r, xtable

I´m trying to produce a sorted table and export in to latex. However it seems xtable cannot cope with sorted tables. Suggestions?

```
   a<-sample(letters,500,replace=T)
    b<-table(a)
    c<-sort(table(a),decreasing=T)
    xtable(b)
    xtable(c)
```

//M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty easy: sort() does not return a table, but an array. Use as.table() to solve your problem :

```
a<-sample(letters,500,replace=T)
b<-table(a)
class(b)
c<-sort(table(a),decreasing=T)
class(c)
d <- as.table(c)
class(d)
xtable(d)
```